# Huge extremely rough provably-composite numbers with no known factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, elliptic-curves, prime-factorization, primality-test

At [Factors of 1000 numbers up to googolplex](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/GOOGOLM.HTM), it's shown that for $G$=googolplex and $k \in (57, 101, 143, 167, 173, 219, 231, 257, 279, 303, 387, 587, 719, 741, 789, 813, 941,  971)$, the number $G-k$ has no prime factors under $3.5 \times 10^{14}$.  I started wondering if any similarly gigantic numbers could be proven composite without the benefit of a known factor.

In 2005, Don Reble constructed an [interesting semiprime](http://www.graysage.com/djr/isp.txt) with elliptic pseudo-curves and the Goldwasser-Kilian ECPP theorem.  No factors are known, but we know the Reble number has exactly 2 prime factors.

Can a gigantic provably-composite number be constructed without the benefit of knowing any factors? Other than finding divisors, are there any [primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) that can quickly show that some carefully designed gigantic number isn't prime?

The number should have no "small" divisors.

Alternately, perhaps a provable-composite might be in a list of extremely rough numbers. A sample fake proof: "Assume for $k\in{1..1000}$ that all values $(10^{100}+k)! +1$ are prime.  That would allow the construction of a Blahblah curve.  By the Someguy theorem, such a construction is impossible. Therefore, at least one $k$ value yields a composite number". Are there any proofs similar to that useful for giving an example of a huge provable composite with no known divisors?

Comment: What's your criterion for gigantic?  Most modern  primality tests don't produce a factor.

Comment: Robert, I'll assume you'll use some neat trick and primality test X to produce some huge composite number.  It should be large enough that alternate primality test Y would take an inconveniently long time to check.

Comment: I will?  I have my doubts about your assumption.

Comment: I think elliptic curves with entries with magnitude about $(10^{100})!$ cannot be handled. Probably the only way to show compositeness for such numbers is finding a non-trivial factor. For the much smaller Fermat-number $\large F_{33}=2^{2^{33}}+1$, it is not known whether it is prime or composite

Comment: A number that fails the Fermat primality test (i.e. has a Fermat witness) will be provably composite. So perhaps one can generate huge random numbers, and (after discarding those with small divisors) test them with Fermat's primality test to find one that is composite. I am not aware of a way to produce an explicit factor of $n$ from a Fermat witness. So this number would be provably composite without knowing any factor.

Comment: Perhaps you could also use Mersenne numbers that fail the Lucas-Lehmer test. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Factorization_of_composite_Mersenne_numbers), $M_{1277}$ is composite and has no known factors (as of June 2019).

Comment: @TobErnack True, Fermat's test doesn't give you a factor of $n$ for a failed witness $b$. OTOH, if $n$ *passes* Fermat's for $b$ but fails the Miller-Rabin test for $b$ then you *can* get a factor of $n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Variants_for_finding_factors for details.