# Does this construction help to factor large numbers efficiently?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, prime-factorization

Here :

[Huge extremely rough provably-composite numbers with no known factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096562/huge-extremely-rough-provably-composite-numbers-with-no-known-factors)

it is mentioned that a large composite number was constructed.

What is incredible, that no factors are known, but it is known that the number has exactly two prime factors.

> Is it known that the prime factors must be "large" ?
>
> Can this method to construct such numbers help to factor large numbers more quickly ?